# Conda VENV over network

Tags: python, macos, networking, jupyter-notebook, conda

I started using miniforge for my MacM1 (used to just run jupyter notebook brom the brew installation).

**My issue is that now I cannot access the jupyter notebook over or outside the network.**

I also installed python and jupyter from brew and tried like that (outside of conda) and it works. It is only when I run jupyter from the miniforge that I have the issue.

Anyone any solution, please?

This is in my congih.json file:
"port": 8888,
"ip": "0.0.0.0",
"allow_origin": "*",
"open_browser": true

(I use that ip for some certificate, anyways, changing it to "*" does nothing, before anyone says that. :))